# Identify a single category and output some code on an archive page

Tags: categories

I'm trying to add some code to an article in an archive page based on its category. I want to add a lock icon to each restricted content item for the category 'members'

I've tried different pieces of code to identify the category but non has worked

This is the block of code it needs adding to:

```
<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class( $css_class ); ?>>
<div class="entry-content">
    <span class="overlay" <?php echo esc_attr( $color_style ); ?>></span>


    <a class="entry-link" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_the_permalink() ); ?>"></a>
    <?php
    if ( naix_get_option( 'portfolio_layout' ) != 'list' ) :
        ?>
        <div class="entry-format">
            <?php echo ! empty( $image_html ) ? $image_html : ''; ?>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php echo ! empty( $bg_image_list ) ? $bg_image_list : ''; ?>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php
        $term_list      = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_category', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );
        $term_list_html = '';
        if ( ! is_wp_error( $term_list ) && $term_list ) {
            $term_list_html = implode( ', ', $term_list );
        }
        ?>
        <span class="entry-cats"><?php echo ! empty( $term_list_html ) ? $term_list_html : ''; ?></span>

        <h2 class="entry-title"><?php echo get_the_title(); ?></h2>
        <span class="entry-cats-bottom"><?php echo ! empty( $term_list_html ) ? $term_list_html : ''; ?></span>
    </header>
</div>
```

I can see that they are output through the flooring code, but I don't know how I can pull out a single category

```
$term_list      = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'portfolio_category', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );
```

This echo's the categories 'Disability, Members' - I just want to be able to add some code if it is set to 'Members'

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use [`has_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/) to determine if a post has a specific term.

```
<?php if ( has_term( 'Members', 'portfolio_category' ) ) : ?>
    <!-- Output icon here. -->
<?php endif; ?>
```